# Java Instantiate Class at Runtime with parameters

Tags: java, dynamic-typing, abstract-factory

I am using an abstract factory to return instances of concrete subclasses.I would like to instantiate the subclasses at runtime given a String of the concrete class name. I also need to pass a parameter to the constructors. The class structure is as follows:

```
abstract class Parent {

  private static HashMap<String, Child> instances = new HashMap<String,Child>()

  private Object constructorParameter;  

  public static Child factory(String childName, Object constructorParam){

     if(instances.keyExists(childName)){
       return instances.get(childName);
     }

     //Some code here to instantiate the Child using constructorParam, 
     //then save Child into the HashMap, and then return the Child.
     //Currently, I am doing:
     Child instance = (Child) Class.forName(childClass).getConstructor().newInstance(new Object[] {constructorParam});
     instances.put(childName, instance);
     return instance;
  }

  //Constructor is protected so unrelated classes can't instantiate
  protected Parent(Object param){ 
    constructorParameter = param;
  }

}//end Parent

class Child extends Parent {
    protected Child(Object constructorParameter){
      super(constructorParameter);
    }
}
```

My attmept above is throwing the following exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Child.<init>()`, followed by the stack trace.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Constructor<?> c = Class.forName(childClass).getDeclaredConstructor(constructorParam.getClass());
c.setAccessible(true);
c.newInstance(new Object[] {constructorParam});
```

The `getConstructor` method takes `Class` arguments to distinguish between constructors. But it returns only public constructors, so you'd need `getDeclaredConstructor(..)`. Then you'd need `setAccessible(true)`

Comment: I tried this and am still seeing the same error. Do I need to alter any constructor signatures? At the moment the signatures don't explicitly expect parameters of type Object, but of something more specific.

Comment: your `constructorParam.getClass()` should return the exact parameter type you are expecting

Comment: Based on your example, I'm not sure what constructorParam.getClass() does. Can you explain your answer better? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**The error : You are invoking the wrong constructor - and the compiler has no way of helping you.**

The problem you were having is simply that you were accessing the zero-argument constructor, rather than the one with arguments.  Remember that constructors in java are ultimately just methods, albeit special ones - and with reflection , all bets are off --- the compiler won't help you if you do something silly.   In your case, you had a scope issue AND also a method signature issue at the same time.

**How to solve this problem and NEVER have to deal with it again in this application**

Its a good idea to wrap constructor invocations in a static helper method that can be *directly tested*, and then put a test explicitly for them in my unit tests, because if the  constructor changes and you forget to update your reflection code, you will again see these cryptic errors creep up again.

You can also simply invoke the constructor as follows :

```
public static Child create(Integer i, String s) throws Exception
{
  Constructor c = Class.forName(childClass).getConstructor(new Object[]{Integer.class, String.class});
  c.setAccessible(true);
  Child instance = (Child) c.newInstance(new Object[]{i , s}) ; 
  return instance;
}
```

and of course add to your tests

```
    @Test 
    public void testInvoke()
    {
        try{ 
   MyClass.create(1,"test");
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Assert.fail("Invocation failed : check api for reflection classes in " + MyClass.class);
   }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you actually pass the parameters to the constructor here?

Comment: @bibs sorry i left that "minor" detail out.  The dynamic constructor invocation of course takes an object array as its arguments, which must match the constructor signature that you acquire from the Class.getConstructor... method .